# Android Random Alarm Tone

Tags: java, c#, android, mobile, alarm

I'm currently working on a alarm app that plays a random alarm tone. I've been able to load a ringtone from the ringtone dialog but I'm thinking of loading a random ringtone directly from the ringtone directory. How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query for available ringtones in the device:

```
RingtoneManager ringtoneMgr = new RingtoneManager(this);
ringtoneMgr.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
Cursor alCursor = ringtoneMgr.getCursor();
```

This alCursor will contain the available ringtone URIs. Now iterate through them & build a URI array:

```
Uri[] alarms = new Uri[alCursor.getCount()];
while(alCursor.moveToNext()) {
    int pos = alCursor.getPosition();
    alarms[pos] = ringtoneMgr.getRingtoneUri(pos);
}
alCursor.close();
```

Now, just generate a random number in the range of 0-alCursor.getCount(), take that ringtone from alarms array & play it.

```
Random r = new Random();
int randNum = r.nextInt(alCursor.getCount());
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, alarms[randNum]);
ringtone.play();
```

This can be an easy approach to achieve your goal. Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks alot =)